# Generatings Charts in perl

Tags: perl, charts

I am trying to understand an old code which generated charts. It takes arrays as input for x and y axis and generates graphs using print statements. I debug the programs to see for loaded modules, but it is not making use of any Perl Modules to do so. I am wondering if anyone could help me in understanding this,

```
print "\@with line\n";
print "\@  line on\n";
print "\@  line loctype view\n";
printf "\@  line %.3f, 0.2, %.3f, 0.8\n", $viewx, $viewx;
print "\@  line linewidth 2\n";
print "\@  line linestyle 1\n";
print "\@  line arrow 0\n";
print "\@line def\n";

print "\@with string\n";
print "\@  string on\n";
print "\@  string loctype view\n";
printf "\@  string %.3f, %.3f\n", $labx, 0.25   unless $top;
printf "\@  string %.3f, %.3f\n", $labx, 0.75   if     $top;
```

Comment: You should try to understand the format of the resulting file. Look at its filename extension.

Answer (score 3):

Those are just print statements.  The `"\@"` escapes the `@` character, so it's not actually using any arrays.  `%.3f` in the 3 `printf` lines is a format specifier, which prints the floating point values passed as arguments (i.e. `$viewx`, `$labx`, `0.25`, `0.75`) to 3 decimal places.

There's not really much there to understand.  Don't see how you mean that this prints charts.

Comment: Not in anything you posted above.